# Почему Celery не запускает таск в очереди?

Tags: django, celery

Подключил в проекте очереди, в результате перестали выполняться таски.

---

settings.py

```
# celery
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('converter', Exchange('converter'), routing_key='converter'),
)
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'converter'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'converter'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'converter'
CELERY_TASK_ROUTES = {
    'streamtv.tasks.start_convertation': {'queue': 'converter'},
}
```

---

celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

celery_app = Celery('core')
celery_app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
celery_app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

---

tasks.py

```
@celery_app.task
def start_convertation(converter_mode=Converter.ConverterMode.COPY):
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    converter = Converter(
        video_converter_mixin_model=Clip,
        media_dir_path=settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        mode=converter_mode,
    )

    return converter.start_convertation()
```

---

Если воркера вызываю так, то всё работает:

```
celery worker -A core --loglevel=info
```

Вывод консоли

```
    The AMQP result backend is scheduled for deprecation in     version 4.0 and removal in version v5.0.     Please use RPC backend or a persistent backend.

  deprecated.warn(

 -------------- celery@xell v4.4.2 (cliffs)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.3.0-51-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29 2020-05-01 20:15:01
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         core:0x7fe2b0bf6430
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . streamtv.tasks.start_convertation

[2020-05-01 20:15:01,555: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2020-05-01 20:15:01,574: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-05-01 20:15:02,618: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2020-05-01 20:15:02,654: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/lexx/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-MyY9SJzP/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:202: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
            leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
[2020-05-01 20:15:02,655: INFO/MainProcess] celery@xell ready.
```

---

А если воркер вызван так, то таски не выполняются

```
celery worker -E -l INFO -n worker.converter -Q converter
```

Вывод консоли

```
 -------------- celery@worker.converter v4.4.2 (cliffs)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.3.0-51-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29 2020-05-02 00:17:42
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x7fc69e892fd0 (.default.Loader)
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: ON
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> converter        exchange=converter(direct) key=converter


[tasks]


[2020-05-02 00:17:42,360: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2020-05-02 00:17:42,375: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-05-02 00:17:43,416: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2020-05-02 00:17:43,448: INFO/MainProcess] celery@worker.converter ready.
```

Comment: Потому что `-A core` забыли указать.

Comment: @andreymal , вы правы, а к тому же я неверно указал `CELERY_ROUTES` (должно быть `CELERY_TASK_ROUTES`). Предлагайте ответом, помечу решением.

Answer (score 0):

Как верно подсказал @andreymal, я при вызове воркера забыл указать `-A core`